# Fiddler AutoResponder alternative for OS X

Tags: macos, proxy, macos-mojave, fiddler

I'm looking for an Mac OS X base alternative for Fiddler's AutoResponders functionality, essentially I want to be able to intercept a remote file request and replace that request with a local file.

Fiddler AutoResponder docs: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/AutoResponder

Any suggestions? Paid or Free.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've decided on Charles, lets me map remote requests to local files or directories: https://www.charlesproxy.com/